# An issue with defining enumerate items: letters are converted to digits

Tags: lists, enumerate

It was difficult for me to find the proper title for the issue that I'm facing. I would like to define a list of cases like:

```
Case 1: 
Case 2:
.....
```

For that, I did the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[Case 1:]
    \item Energy value
    \item Optimizer
\end{enumerate}
```

When I compile it, I get the following:

```
C1se 1: Energy value
C1se 2: Optimizer
```

The letter `a` in the word `Case` has changed to 1 which I don't know why !!

I even tried the word `Scenario`, and I get it like `Scen1r1o`

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Just guessing: try `\begin{enumerate}[{Case} 1:]`. If it doesn't work, please post a compilable example.

Comment: please always provide an example document, you are using (without saying) the `enumerate` package syntax and that requires `[{Case }1:]` here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved by changing the line `\begin{enumerate}[Case 1:]` to `\begin{enumerate}[{Case} 1:]` and the same with the word `Scenario`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your answer into a compilable code so that people can just copy-paste it to try.